# xpages views alternating row colors

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am trying to add alternating row colors in a dynamicViewControl. I found this article by Mark Hughes http://dominoextnd.blogspot.com/2009/10/xpages-alternate-view-row-colors-made.html but when I try to enter rowEven, rowOdd in the rowClasses I get an error message about invalid character (comma) I have tried all sorts of different ways without success. What am I doing wrong. I have seen it in the examples, but I cannot reproduce that

Comment: It works in my case. Does this code snippet `<xe:dynamicViewPanel id="dynamicViewPanel1" rowClasses="even, odd">` give you error?

Comment: Jim, the code snippet from Naveen matches what I use too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use css:

```
.someClass tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Naveen's solution worked fine. I just need to get more in the habit of working in the source code rather than the GUI for alot of things. Thanks!